# Replace numbers in string by respective result of a substraction

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, replace

I have a string like this:

```
"foo 15 bar -2hello 4 asdf+2"
```

I'd like to get:

```
"foo 14 bar -3hello 3 asdf+1"
```

I would like to replace every number (sequence of digits as signed base-10 integers) with the result of a subtraction executed on each of them, one for each number.

I've written a ~50 LOC function that iterates on characters, separating signs, digits and other text, applying the function and recombining the parts. Although it has one issue my intent with the question is *not* to review it. Instead I'm trying to ask, what is the pythonic way to solve this, is there an easier way?

For reference, [here is my function](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/13t4vGFep3GLuGWbJScv/) with the known issue, but my intention is *not* asking for a review but finding the most pythonic way instead.

**edit** to answer the wise [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660224/replace-numbers-in-string-by-respective-result-of-a-substraction?noredirect=1#comment29195262_19660224) of [Janne Karila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222914/janne-karila):

- preferred: retain sign if given: `+2` should become `+1`
- preferred: zero has no sign: `+1` should become `0`
- preferred: no spaces: `asdf - 4` becomes `asdf - 3`
- required: only one sign: `-+-2` becomes `-+-3`

---

**edit** on popular demand here is my buggy code :)

**DISCLAIMER: Please note I'm not interested in fixing this code. I'm asking if there is a better approach than something like mine.**

```
def apply_to_digits(some_str,handler):
    sign = "+"
    started = 0
    number = []
    tmp = []
    result = []
    for idx,char in enumerate(some_str):
        if started:
            if not char.isdigit():
                if number:
                    ss = sign + "".join(number)
                    rewritten = str(handler(int(ss)))
                    result.append(rewritten)
                elif tmp:
                    result.append("".join(tmp))
                number = []
                tmp = []
                sign = "+"
                started = 0
                # char will be dealt later
            else:
                number.append(char)
                continue
        if char in "-+":
            sign = char
            started = 1
            if tmp:
                result.append("".join(tmp))
                tmp = []
            tmp.append(char)
            continue
        elif char.isdigit():
            started = 1
            if tmp:
                result.append("".join(tmp))
                tmp = []
            number.append(char)
        else:
            tmp.append(char)
    if number:
        ss = sign + "".join(number)
        rewritten = str(handler(int(ss)))
        result.append(rewritten)
    if tmp:
        result.append("".join(tmp)), tmp
    return "".join(result)
#
```

**DISCLAIMER: Please note I'm not interested in fixing this code. I'm asking if there is a better approach than something like mine.**

Comment: Please paste the code here, that is what SO meant to be.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy yes; I intendedly didn't do so because it tends to call for reviews, what is not what I want. I'm just looking for an easier way. Nevertheless I'll paste it.

Comment: You tagged the code with regex, so why not use it?

Comment: @sweeneyrod well I don't really have a good reason, but I haven't came up with the regex solution yet.

Comment: How exactly should it deal with signs? Should `+1` become `+0` or `0`? Is it OK to change `+2` to `1` omitting the sign? What if there are multiple signs like `-+-2`? Spaces between sign and number?

Comment: @naxa regexes probably are not going to be much use here, other than to recognize a sequence of characters that represent a number - regexes are notoriously bad at actually doing things like arithmetic...

Comment: @JanneKarila with `-+-2`, only the last sign should be part of the number. `--+2` is to become `--+1`. `+1` is to become `0`.

Comment: @JanneKarila edited the question to answer other points in your comment. **edited** to explain that not all requirements are 'hard', some are OK both ways.

Comment: sorry I made an edit that changes the post, but reversed it. I shall ask it as another question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using regex, and using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> pattern = "(-?\d+)|(\+1)"
>>> def sub_one(match):
        return str(int(match.group(0)) - 1)

>>> text = "foo 15 bar -2hello 4 asdf+2"
>>> re.sub(pattern, sub_one, text)
'foo 14 bar -3hello 3 asdf+1'
```

The regex `(-?\d+)|(\+1)` will either capture an optional `-` sign and one or more digits, OR the literal sequence `+1`. That way, the regex will make sure that all of your requirements when converting digits work properly.

The regex `(-?\d+)` by itself does the right thing most of the time, but the `(\+1)` exists to make sure that the string `+1` always converts to zero, without a sign. If you change your mind, and want `+1` to convert to `+0`, then you can just use only the first part of the regex: `(-?d+)`.

You could probably compress this all into a one-liner if you wanted:

```
def replace_digits(text):
    return re.sub("(-?\d+)|(\+1)", lambda m: str(int(m.group(0)) - 1), text)
```